# Tomcat + Wicket: UTF-8 chars not rendering properly

Tags: html, tomcat, utf-8, wicket

I have a Wicket app with some pages containing accented chars, entered as UTF-8, e.g. "résumé".

When I debug the app via the traditional Wicket `Start.java` class (which invokes an embedded Jetty server) all is good.  However when I try deploying to a local Tomcat instance, it renders as "r√©sum√©".

My document looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
   résumé
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what `curl -I` returns for the page when running on Jetty:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en-US
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 13545
Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
```

And here's what Tomcat returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2011 14:36:45 GMT
```

Comment: Are you sure the document is saved as utf8?

Comment: @Gerben- yes, my IDE is configured to save it as UTF-8. Interestingly, the unix "file" command reports it as "HTML document text", but if I strip away the HTML and leave behind the "résumé" string, it does report it as "UTF-8 Unicode text".

Comment: Just a wild stab in the dark but you can try starting your web server with `-Djaxp.debug=1` to figure out if there's a difference between the XML parsers used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that Wicket doesn't detect the encoding of the markup files correctly. They are encoded as UTF-8, so non-ASCII chars are represented by two bytes. But Wicket doesn't know that and reads them as two separate characters. Those two characters are then encoded as UTF-8 again in the response. Since the "square root" characters is not ANSI itself you should actually see *three* bytes per é in the response.

Anyway, you need to fix this markup encoding interpretation. Checkout the Wicket source code for XMLReader#init().

It reads like Wicket tries three things the find out about the encoding of a markup file:

1. Evaluates the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration in beginning of the markup file. (Missing for you?)
2. Uses the default encoding specified by `Application#getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding(String)`
3. Uses the OS default.

It looks like are missing 1 and 2 at the moment so Wicket falls back to 3 which doesn't work in your case. So try any of the other two.

Comment: Indeed, adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to the top of the .html file did the trick.

Comment: This is working great. I prefer option 2, because you can do that on a central point. Besides, HTML5 (if you are using it) is not XML, so option 1 would be somehow a hack.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why this is needed, but here's a workaround that solved this for me:

```
public class Application extends WebApplication
{
    @Override
    protected void init()
    {
        getRequestCycleSettings().setResponseRequestEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    }
}
```

To give credit where it is due, I found this solution [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/UTF-8-bug-in-wicket-Or-in-Tomcat-td1876722.html).