# java app: html pages encoding issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans, webserver

OK, I searched for the solution for two days and I surprisingly still haven't found an answer. I have java app (NetBeans 7.2, tomcat 7, windows 7) which is displaying international (Russian in my case) characters wrong when I run it locally.

The following is done:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

is set in the pages.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...
```

is set in Tomcat. I also tried setting '-Dfile.encoding = UTF8' as JVM parameter but still it displays the text wrong (it's just simple text in the .html files, not pulled from DB). The file encoding is UTF-8 also. When I go to our local servers running the app it displays fine! So I guess the problem is with my machine (my system locale is set to Russian). Also my colleagues running Russian Windows do not encounter this problem. I have English Windows.

Comment: Is your browser forcing page encoding to something else?

Comment: Maybe it's only the browser. Have you enabled the automatic selection of the page encoding? (for IE:  Right-click the webpage, point to Encoding, and then click Auto-Select.)

Comment: nope, and default character encoding is set to UTF-8. Also the problem is with all browsers I have (FF, IE, Chrome). All of them show normal letters when I view app deployed on our local testing server, but not locally.

Comment: Do you have at the top `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`? This send an UTF-8 header. Which supercedes the meta tag.

Comment: Carlo Pellegrini, it's in all browsers like I said. Probably I should add that not all the characters display wrong but just those that are hardcoded in the html page. The ones pulled from the .properties files are displayed ok.

Comment: Joop Eggen, I think <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> is related to JSP. We are not using JSP, we use java+wicket+other stuff

Comment: Maybe you have set the encoding in Tomcat: `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="Cp1251"/>`; that URIEncoding. http://serverfault.com/questions/236391/how-can-i-change-the-default-encoding-of-a-tomcat-server-container

Comment: Retagged this with web server and apache, as that is what will be causing the problem rather than Java or NetBeans.

Comment: @JoopEggen, here is that it looks like in my tomcat server.xml `<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript" />`. Setting `JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"` didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally! Setting

```
Application#getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("UTF-8")
```

at the application startup helped me. So the problem was with Wicket rather than Tomcat. I found answer here - [Tomcat + Wicket: UTF-8 chars not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801146/tomcat-wicket-utf-8-chars-not-rendering-properly)